# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

The program is written using JSP and Servlets. For Database actions is used Hibernate. When I try to save data into database my program throws an exception.
I have found at stackoverflow some answers, but they didn't help me.
I use IntelliJ IDEA and Apache Tomcat.
Could you tell me what the problem can be here?

Registration class:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Registration")
```

public class Registration extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String str = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(str);

    UserRegData userRegData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, UserRegData.class);

    long tmpId = new Random().nextLong();
    if (tmpId < 0) {
        tmpId *= -1;
    }

    userRegData.setId(new Long(tmpId));

    System.out.println("\n>>>>>> User registration Data :");
    System.out.println(userRegData.toString());

    //set user data into the object for inserting into table in Database
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(userRegData.getEmail());
    user.setCity(userRegData.getCity());
    user.setCountry(userRegData.getCountry());
    user.setDateOfBirth(userRegData.getDateOfBirth());
    user.setId(userRegData.getId());
    user.setPhoneNumber(userRegData.getPhoneNumber());
    user.setSex(user.getSex());

    //set user login and password for inserting into table in Database
    try {

        UserAuthData userAuthData = new UserAuthData(userRegData.getId(), Hashing.hashString(userRegData.getLogin()),
                Hashing.hashString(userRegData.getPassword()));

        System.out.println("users login: " + userAuthData.getLogin());
        System.out.println("users pass:  " + userAuthData.getPassword());

        boolean allusersTable = ManagingData.insIntoTable(user, user.getId());
        boolean users_login_dataTable = ManagingData.insIntoTable(userAuthData, userAuthData.getId());

        if (allusersTable == true && users_login_dataTable == true) {
            System.out.println("user has been registered!");
        }

    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        System.out.println("No such Algorithm!!!!!!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.setStatus(201);
    response.sendRedirect("/page_of_user");
    System.out.println("response has been sent!");
}
```

Annotated class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "allusers")
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private long phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "sex")
    private String sex;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String email, long phoneNumber, String country, String city, Date dateOfBirth, String sex) {
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(long phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

The method which throws exception is:

```
 public void setId(Long id) {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .buildServiceRegistry();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    while(true) {
        if (session.get(User.class, id) == null) {
            this.id = id;
            break;
        }else{
            id = new Random().nextLong();
            if(id<0){
                id *= (-1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The thrown exception is:

> 14-Aug-2018 02:53:10.544 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Registration] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   Users.UserRegData.setId(UserRegData.java:102)     at
>   Actions.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:35)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Maven dependency for Hibernate is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: please, edit your post to attach Registration class

Comment: I have attached Registration class.

Comment: Have you already done a "mvn clean install" from the console and then a (in eclipse so-called) "project clean"?

Comment: I've tried to do mvn clean install, but there was build failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```